# WebView bug - replace selected text in ContentEditable

Tags: javascript, android, webview, contenteditable

So, here's the thing.  I have a WebView displaying a contenteditable div.  Now, when I select text, everything's all fine and good, and via javascript interfaces I can see that document.getSelection() returns what it ought.  However, when I type something, rather than replace the selected text in the current node, it appears to replace the text in the first node at the corresponding offsets.  For instance, if I have

```
Blah1
Blah2
Blah3
Blah4
```

and I select "ah4" and type "q", I end up with

```
Blq
Blah2
Blah3
Blah4
```

instead of

```
Blah1
Blah2
Blah3
Blq
```

I've noticed that if I run it on the emulator with the *hardware* keyboard rather than the soft keyboard, it works fine.

I've tried to intercept the event to do stuff manually, but neither the `onKeyListener` nor the javascript `onKeyDown` nor `onKeyPress` registers an event when it's replacing text.  Javascript `onInput` registers, but only after the replacement has occurred.

Any ideas how to circumvent this?

---

Further info:

As it turns out, when text is selected and a key is pressed on the soft keyboard, that keypress does not pass through the activity's dispatchKeyEvent method.  I hypothesize that this difference is fundamental to occurrence of the glitch.  Anybody know why and how this would happen, as well as why it would cause a glitch?  I'm going to go see if I can trace the path of code execution.

Comment: If you override the `dispatchKeyEvent` method in your activity, it will receive key events. As for your actual problem, this is probably a bug in the webview. I'm not sure how to circumvent it, however.

Comment: @Randy Hmm, actually, that was a good thing to try - when text is selected, the next key press from the soft keyboard DOESN'T pass through `dispatchKeyEvent`, and yields glitchy behavior.

Comment: that's odd and good to know. I have an app which has implemented support for keyboard 'wedges' and this would break it :/

Comment: Well, it MAY only happen when text is selected specifically in a contenteditable div, but I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Hah!  Found a solution!  After way too much mucking around in the android source, I eventually tried the following: subclass the WebView, and override the following method:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
}
```

And that does it!  Granted, the selection (the blue stripe) lingers visually after you type, but it replaces the text you expect, at least, and the stripe doesn't affect anything.  Plus, it did that before, anyway.  I expect there's a fairly easy way to get rid of it, too.